# Can't block access to a file using .htaccess

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

I tried this in the .htaccess file:

```
<Files ./user/config.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

But I could still access the file. What am I doing wrong?

The file is located in /public_html/user/config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried without the `./` ?

If removing that doesn't work, how about putting the `.htaccess` file in the user folder, and then just use `<Files config.php>`?  That is probably more efficient anyway.

Other things you can try can be found in [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).